# How to open a window in Vivado using Tcl script?

Tags: tcl, xilinx, vivado

I'd like to open a **`.vhd`** and **`.vhi`** file in window for editing in Vivado from `Tcl` Console, but I can't find any command for that.

Answer (score 1):

As of at least Vivado 2014.2 any unrecognized Tcl command will be sent to the OS shell for execution, so you can simply open whatever editor you like as if you were not in the Tcl shell. It basically automatically runs exec for you. Older versions you may have to run exec yourself.

eg

> nedit file.vhd

Answer (score 0):

Vivado being a design tool works on projects instead of individual files. So to edit a file, say *xyz.vhd*, the file needs to be part of a project. This can be done through Tcl console by creating a new project, adding *xyz.vhd* file to it and then loading the project.

1. Create a new project using the following command:

   `project -new`
2. Add files:

   `add_file -vhd "xyz.vhd"`
3. Save the project and run.

   ```
   project -save
   project -run
   ```

You can find further resources at this [link](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~greenwd/scripting.pdf).